# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException error when trying to run

Tags: android, database

I'm trying to get data from my database, so that it would change an EditText value, but I'm not sure why I am getting a CursorIndexOutOfBounds exception.

my database code is as follow

```
public String getActivityData(Integer name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM VenueTable WHERE _id = " + name+";";
    Cursor a = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

    String facility = a.getString(a.getColumnIndex("facilities"));
    return facility;
}
```

Below is the code where I use use the data provided

```
facility1 = listViewd.getActivityData(post);

facility = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.facilityName);
facility.setText(facility1);
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error, I hope someone can point out my error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need check is cursor Empty or Not. I always do:

```
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        do {

        // your code. Adding to ArrayList etc.

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the cursor on the first record:

```
a.moveToFirst();
```

soon after filling it (after running the `rawQuery()`).
Otherwise, it's positioned **before the first record**.

Which means, at position **-1**, not at position **0**.

Comment: Cursor never can be null. It created with CursorFactory. If we have no data - SQL returns cursor without any data. Proof : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java#1252